# Clarification about the proof of the Chinese Remainder Theorem

Tags: proof-explanation, chinese-remainder-theorem

Near the end, the proof states that no prime that divides $m_i$ for $i = 1, 2,\ldots, k-1$ can divide $m_k$. But why does this imply that $\gcd{(m_1m_2\cdots m_{k-1},m_k)=1}$? I've been thinking about this for a long time, and I really can't understand it.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\gcd(a,c)=1$ and $\gcd(b,c)=1$, then $\gcd(ab,c)=1$, because neither $a$ nor $b$ have any prime factors in common with $c$, and therefore nor does $ab$. This property holds because the $\gcd$ function is [multiplicative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_function).

Comment: Is it not possible for the gdc to be greater than 1 if we consider the product of the primes of $ab$ and $c$ instead of the primes themselves? For example, neither 2 nor 5 are divisible by 10, but 2*5 certainly is. To be honest, I'm not even sure of what I'm talking about right now.

Comment: If $\gcd(ab,c)\gt1$ then $c$ would have to have some prime in common with either $a$ or $b$, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

A common divisor of $m_1, m_2, \dots, m_k$ Has to divide every one of $m_1, m_2, \dots, m_k$. So if a prime number divides  $m_1, m_2, \dots, m_{k-1}$ and also $m_k$, then it is also a common divisor of  $m_1, m_2, \dots, m_k$. This is a contradiction if the gcd is $1$.

Answer (score 0):

To help you understand the Chinese Remainder Theorem: Let $P=\prod_{i=1}^k m_i$ where the $m_i$'s are non-$0$ and pair-wise co-prime.

(1). We establish that  if $x\equiv y \pmod {m_i}$ for every $i$ then $P|(x-y).$

(2). Let $[[P]]=\{1,...,P\}$ and let $S$ be the set of all $k$-tuples $(a_1,...,a_k)$ where $1\le a_i\le m_i$ for each $i.$

Let $F:P\to S$ where $F(x)=(\,f_1(x),...,f_k(x)\;)$ with  $x\equiv f_i(x)\pmod {m_i}$ for each $i$.

Now $F$ is a 1-to-1 function. Because $F(x)=F(y)$ implies $x\equiv f_i(x)=f_i(y)\equiv y \pmod {m_i}$ for every $i$, which by (1) implies $P|(x-y)\land |x-y|<P
$, implying $x=y$.

So the finite sets $[[P]],S$  have the same number of members, and $F:[[[P]]\to S$ is 1-to-1. So for each $(a_1,...,a_k)\in S$ there is exactly one $x\in [[P]]$ such that $F(x)=(a_1,...,a_k).$